# GoToState from within ItemTemplate

Tags: silverlight, vsm

Anybody figured out how to activate a visual state within the namescope of the ItemsControl from within a DataTemplate applied to said ItemsControl's ItemTemplate?

You obviously can't select the target from within Blend. I was wondering if there was some obvious loop hole that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to create your own derived DataTemplate that can do special logic, think something named a VisualStateDataTemplate?

*Just  thought, I haven't tried it.*